# Keyboard shortcuts in c# wpf

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I make shortcut key in main window in WPF, for example when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`CommandBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx)

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings> 
    <CommandBinding  
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" 
        Executed="_HandleApplicationOpenCommandExecute"/>         
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```